About the Generator Matrix Structure in the Paper "Efficient Erasure Correcting Code"
I am new to coding theory and I would like to ask about the structure of the generator matrix $G$ of the paper "Efficient Erasure Correcting Code" of Luby et al.  here (https://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/spielman/PAPERS/eraseIT.pdf) since I am not sure if my understanding is correct.
According to Section 2A the paper here:

I understand that the codeword $C=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ has $k$ message bits, $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_k$ and $n-k$ check bits, $x_{k+1},x_{k+2},\dots,x_n$, and each for each $k+1\leq j \leq n$, we have $x_j=x_{i_1}+x_{i_2}+\dots+x_{i_d}$ for some $1 \leq i_1,i_2,\dots,i_d \leq k$. In this way, we can actually compute $x_{k+1},x_{k+2},\dots,x_n$ in parallel from $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_k$ (i.e., we do not have to compute them sequentially in the sense that we must compute $x_{j+1}$ from $x_j$). Is my understanding correct? If yes, then the matrix $G$ here actually has the form $G=\begin{bmatrix} I \\ G' \end{bmatrix}$ where $G'$ is a sparse matrix with at most $d$ non-zeroes in each row, is it true?
Now consider the general case $\mathbb{F}_p$ instead of $\mathbb{F}_2$ for a prime number $p$, then do we have $x_j=x_{i_1}+x_{i_2}+\dots+x_{i_d}$ or $x_j+x_{i_1}+x_{i_2}+\dots+x_{i_d}=0$ (the parity check constraint)? Since, in the former case, then for general prime $p$, we have $G=\begin{bmatrix} I \\ G' \end{bmatrix}$ where $G'$ is a sparse matrix, having entries in ${0,1}$, with at most $d$ non-zeroes in each row. Otherwise, $G$ still have the same structure, except that $G'$ has entries in ${-1,0}$. Is my understanding correct?
Finally, thank you very much for reading my questions.
